# How does Postman generate oAuth 1.0a signatures?

Tags: oauth, postman, oauth-1.0a

I'm attempting to connect to an oAuth 1.0 authenticated endpoint but the signature that Postman creates does not match the signature we expect in our code. As far as I can see all the parameters that I have added are correct (Url, consumer_key, consumer_secret, nonce, timestamp, HMAC-SHA1) but Postman just seems to generate a different signature with these details. Does anyone know how Postman creates the signature?

Comment: When I use postman, I get a success message from the API I'm calling. My guess is a HASH of the URL I'm calling, then HMAC_SHA1 of that results in signature in hex format?

Comment: Not sure if you already figured out the answer to this question, but you could try grabbing the raw `curl` command that Postman generates to see if the signature looks as expected.

To get the curl command for any given endpoint you can simply click on `Code` underneath the `Save` button.